# Error 403 blocked by Cors when I try to make a POST using Fetch from React

Tags: cors, fetch

I am using this code to try to post a Login to an API that is hosted on AWS

```
const submitLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await axios({
        method: 'post', 
        url: '******************',
        data: {
            'username' : '***',
            'password' : '***'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'application/json',


        }
      });
        console.log(response);
```

the server answers the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://*************' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code in Stach Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: It's because your server. you should allow access from other origins in your server. We can help more if we see your server code. Is it with Express.js??